# How to outsource code to other computers to run perpetually?

Tags: web-scraping, automation, bots

I’ve created a web scraper that scrapes info from web pages and populates the parameters of/makes an API post that is running perpetually (there are some tens of thousands of pages to scrape and each request takes about 1 second to prevent too many request, or 429, errors).

I am wanting to streamline the process by outsourcing the code to other IP addresses. If I run more requests from my IP, the site will likely begin to block the requests. The goal would be to have 4 or 5 instances of this code running perpetually.

The only solution I know of that would work is using VMs to run additional instances of the code, but I imagine there are simpler ways to achieve this goal.

Comment: Bad question, since asking for resources without even mention of prior research of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"outsourcing" is the wrong word.

### Terminology

You want "remote execution" or some kind of [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing), and probably even [remote procedure calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

You could use [JSONRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC). or [RPC/XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call) or [XML-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) or [CORBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) or [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) above HTTP. You'll find (on [github](https://github.com), [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/), [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net), in your favorite [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), etc...) many [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) to help you (even [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/)). You could even find distributed libraries for web scraping.

You could even more generally do some [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) (consider [0mq](http://zeromq.org/)) or do some [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). You probably want some [text-based protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) (since they are easier to debug, e.g. a JSON based one) above perhaps [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).

### Details are *operating system* specific.

If on Linux, read [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/), then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) and related, then [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html).